# Tracking location with GSM tower triangulation

Tags: signal, gsm, cellphone, python

I want to track location with GSM tower triangulation.

I searched and I found [this API for GSM positioning](https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning/dev_guide/topics/example-gsm.html).

```
{
  "gsm": [{
    "mcc": 262,
    "mnc": 1,
    "lac": 5126,
    "cid": 16504,
    "nmr": [
      { "bsic": "6", "bcch": "82" },
      { "bsic": "7", "bcch": "85" },
      { "bsic": "12", "bcch": "93" },
      { "bsic": "13", "bcch": "88" },
      { "bsic": "19", "bcch": "88" }
    ]
  }]
}
```

It requires the shown GSM information.

I don't understand what "nmr" is.

How can I find "nmr" information of GSM?

Comment: why can you not search the web?  the answers are all there

Comment: I searched but I don't understand exactly what is nmr.

Comment: @Sun: In the context of GSM, "NMR" stands for "Network Measurement Report."  Despite having written (professionally) several programs that use GSM modems, I do not recall having seen the AT commands needed to get the NMR values.  I'm also not having any success looking them up.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the NMR is in the "Cell Broadcast Messages" that you can request using the "AT+CSCB" command.